# How to add the innerhtml first and then add eventlistner to the element that follows

Tags: javascript

1) why does First button show up on the DOM and not the second button

2) For the second Button, I want the greeting to be displayed first on the DOM and then add eventlistner to it. How do I achieve this?

```js
var greeting = "hi"
var greetingSpace = document.getElementById('exampleTwo');
greetingSpace.innerHTML = greeting;


document.getElementById('SecondButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  greetingSpace.innerHTML = "hello";
})
```

```html
<!-- button shows -->
<div id="exampleOne">
  <button id="firstButton"> First button </button>
</div>


<!-- Button doesn't show and the error says 'Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null'-->
<div id="exampleTwo">
  <button id="SecondButton"> Second Button </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your js code After closing of body.And put even Listner as first Satement .

Comment: Just comment out `greetingSpace.innerHTML = greeting;` line and your 2nd button will show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `greetingSpace.innerHTML` you are overwriting the second button and removing it from the DOM.

The simplest solution would be to draw the greeting into a separate DOM element, instead of the `#exampleTwo` which contains the button:

```js
var greeting = "hi"
var greetingSpace = document.getElementById('greetingSpace');
greetingSpace.innerHTML = greeting;


document.getElementById('SecondButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  greetingSpace.innerHTML = "hello";
})
```

```html
<div id="exampleOne">
  <button id="firstButton"> First button </button>
</div>

<div id="exampleTwo">
<div id="greetingSpace"></div>
  <button id="SecondButton"> Second Button </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are overwriting the `exampleTwo` element's content using `innerHTML` property, using

```
greetingSpace.innerHTML = greeting;
```

So,  the button doesn't exists anymore as a result you are getting the error. Create another `<div>`/`<span>` for `greetingSpace` and your button will start showing